# sorting data into a tree

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the following data:

```
var data = [
    { index : 1, sort : 10, parent : 0 },
    { index : 2, sort : 7, parent : 0 },
    { index : 3, sort : 15, parent : 1 },
    { index : 4, sort : 4, parent : 0 },
    { index : 5, sort : 13, parent : 1 },
    { index : 6, sort : 20, parent : 5 },
    { index : 7, sort : 2, parent : 8 },
    { index : 8, sort : 6, parent : 5 },
];
```

How do I efficiently sort this by both parent ID and the sort value so that I end up with:

```
var data = [
    { index : 4, sort : 4, parent : 0 },    
    { index : 2, sort : 7, parent : 0 },
    { index : 1, sort : 10, parent : 0 },
    { index : 5, sort : 13, parent : 1 },
    { index : 8, sort : 6, parent : 5 },
    { index : 7, sort : 2, parent : 8 },
    { index : 6, sort : 20, parent : 5 },   
    { index : 3, sort : 15, parent : 1 },
];
```

This is a tree structure. Each element is immediately followed by any children and all elements on the same branch are sorted by the sort value.

The best I can come up with is to first sort by parent and then do a second sort on each branch. This seems inefficient.

Edit: The example sort order was wrong. I've corrected it.

Edit for clarification: Each nested branch needs to appear immediately below the parent value, not at the end of the branch.

Edit: further corrections to data.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is not your original approach, but you could build an actual tree from your data, like this:

```
function TreeNode(data) {
  this.data     = data;
  this.parent   = null;
  this.children = [];
}
TreeNode.comparer = function (a, b) { 
  return a.data.sort < b.data.sort ? 0 : 1; 
};
TreeNode.prototype.sortRecursive = function () {
  this.children.sort(TreeNode.comparer);
  for (var i=0, l=this.children.length; i<l; i++) {
    this.children[i].sortRecursive();
  }
  return this;
};

function toTree(data) {
  var nodeById = {}, i = 0, l = data.length, node;

  nodeById[0] = new TreeNode(); // that's the root node

  for (i=0; i<l; i++) {  // make TreeNode objects for each item
    nodeById[ data[i].index ] = new TreeNode(data[i]);
  }
  for (i=0; i<l; i++) {  // link all TreeNode objects
    node = nodeById[ data[i].index ];
    node.parent = nodeById[node.data.parent];
    node.parent.children.push(node);
  }
  return nodeById[0].sortRecursive();
}
```

With this set-up, you will get your nodes neatly nested with a simple call:

```
var tree = toTree(data);
```

```
TreeNode:0
  parent  -> null
  data    -> undefined
  childen -> Array[
    TreeNode:1
      parent  -> TreeNode:0
      data    -> { index : 4, sort :  4, parent : 0 }
      childen -> Array[]
    TreeNode:2
      parent  -> TreeNode:0
      data    -> { index : 2, sort :  7, parent : 0 }
      childen -> Array[]
    TreeNode:3
      parent  -> TreeNode:0
      data    -> { index : 1, sort : 10, parent : 0 }
      childen -> Array[
        TreeNode:4
          parent  -> TreeNode:3
          data    -> { index : 5, sort : 13, parent : 1 }
          childen -> Array[
          ]
        TreeNode:5
          parent  -> TreeNode:3
          data    -> { index : 3, sort : 15, parent : 1 }
          childen -> Array[
            ... and so on ...
          ]
      ]
  ]
```

Once you have that tree object, you can do a number of things with it, including traversing it recursively in the expected order.

To do this, you could add a helper function that does depth-first traversal and executes a payload function `f` for every node:

```
TreeNode.prototype.walk = function(f, recursive) {
  for (var i=0, l=this.children.length; i<l; i++) {
    var child = this.children[i];
    f.apply(child, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2));
    if (recursive) child.walk.apply(child, arguments);
  }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
tree.walk(function () { console.log(this.data) }, true);
```

which would produce:

```
{ index: 4, sort:  4, parent: 0}
{ index: 2, sort:  7, parent: 0}
{ index: 1, sort: 10, parent: 0}
{ index: 5, sort: 13, parent: 1}
{ index: 8, sort:  6, parent: 5}
{ index: 7, sort:  2, parent: 8}
{ index: 6, sort: 20, parent: 5}
{ index: 3, sort: 15, parent: 1}
```

Use more complex payload functions for other effects, like adding table rows in a table with jQuery or items to a `<select>` box.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, that is a nice bit of OO Javascript. More efficient than mine as well. Also a great example of recursion.

Comment: @SystemicPlural: Thanks. Also see the functionality added a few minutes ago.

Comment: Thanks again. I decided to benchmark. Your answer is about 250 times faster than mine. Out of curiosity, I then converted your answer to a singleton closure and gained a further 10%. Not sure why. It can only handle one tree as it is a singleton, but that is fine for my use case.

Comment: Nice! If you could post that code as an answer of your own, I'd like to have a look at it.

Comment: I've posted it below. I've changed a few variable names to reflect the sample data in this post. Hopefully not broken anything.

Comment: Why to sort at the end and use a recursion for it. Would it be not better to sort only one time at the beginning?

Comment: @Alexandre I think it would be better, yes. Didn't occur to me when I wrote this answer.

Comment: Any ideas of how performatic is that approach? Any benchmarks?

Comment: Make measurements of you need them. The tree-building runs in linear time (`O(n)`), it's just two array iterations after all. The sorting takes a little extra time, which is not necessary if the data comes pre-sorted. So...

Answer (score 3):

Tomalak request above that I post my singleton version of their answer. Here it is:

```
/**
 * Represents sorted results in a tree structure.
 */
Tree = (function() {

    /**
     *
     * @type {Object} nodes Holds all the nodes in a flat format.
     * @type {Object} nodes.data The data that is held in this node.
     * @type {Object} nodes.parent Points to the parent object of this node.
     * @type {Array} nodes.children An array of the child nodes of this node.
     */
    var nodes = {};

    /**
     * @type {Object} root_node A Reference to the root node in nodes.
     */
    var root_node;

    /**
     * A sort function to sort the nodes by the data.sort value in each node.
     * @param {Number} a The first node to compare
     * @param {Number} b The second node to compare
     * @return {Boolean} Swap these nodes or not.
     */
    var comparer = function (a, b) {
        return a.data.sort < b.data.sort ? 0 : 1;
    };

    /**
     * Sorts all the nodes so that they are in the correct order according to each nodes data.sort value.
     * @param {Object} node A reference to the node in the nodes object.
     */
    var sortRecursive = function (node) {
        node.children.sort(comparer);
        var len = node.children.length;
        for (var i = 0 ; i < len ; i++) {
            sortRecursive(node.children[i]);
        }
    };

    /**
     * Create a new node with the passed in data.
     * @param {Object} data The data that is associated with this node.
     */
    var create_node = function(data){
        var node = {
            data : data,
            parent : null,
            children : []
        };
        return node;
    };

    return {

        /**
         * Create a new tree of data
         * @param {Array} data An array of data objects to transorm into a tree.
         * @param {Array} data[].index The id of this node
         * @param {Array} data[].parent The parent id of this node.
         * @param {Number} root_id Id of the root node.
         */
        create : function(data, root_id){

            // Clear any previous data
            nodes = {};

            var i;
            var len = data.length;

            // Create an empty root node
            nodes[root_id] = create_node({});
            root_node = nodes[root_id];

            // Make node objects for each data item
            for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
                if(typeof data[i].sort !== "undefined")
                    nodes[ data[i].index ] = create_node(data[i]);
            }

            // Link all TreeNode objects
            for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
                var node = nodes[data[i].index];
                node.parent = nodes[node.data.parent];
                node.parent.children.push(node);
            }
            sortRecursive(nodes[root_id]);
        },

        /**
         * Walk through the nodes in nested and then sorted order, calling the passed in callback for each node.
         * @param {Function} callback A callback function to call for each node.
         * @param {Boolean} recursive Should the walkback be recursive, or just fetch the top level results.
         * @param {Object|Undefined} node The node that is currently being walked.
         *                                Ommit this value and the root node will be used.
         */
        walk : function(callback, recursive, node) {
            if(typeof node == "undefined")
                node = root_node;

            for (var i = 0, len = node.children.length; i < len; i++) {
                var child = node.children[i];
                callback.apply(child, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2));
                if (recursive)
                    arguments.callee(callback, recursive, child);
            }
        }

    };
})();
```

Populate the tree with:

```
Tree.create(unsorted_data, parent_id);
```

Fetch a sorted array with:

```
var sorted = [];
Tree.walk(function(){
    sorted.push(this.data);
}, true);
```

Comment: +1 for sharing your solution. FYI `arguments.callee` is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on arguments.callee

Answer (score 0):

Edit: ditch this, it doesn't work.

This is the best I've managed. Which should bubble sort it. I've not tested it yet. I'll leave the best answer open to see if anyone can improve on it.

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.parent - b.parent;
});

var changes = true;
while (changes){
    changes = false;
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i].parent === data[i-1].parent && data[i].sort < data[i-1].sort){
            var tmp = data[i-1];
            data[i-1] = data[i];
            data[i] = tmp;
            changes = true;   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This algorithm gives me the exact same result as mine. Which is different than the one you ask for in your question.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts I've come up with this. It works, but is not very elegant. Could also do with abstracting into its own class.

```
// Initial sort places items in the correct sort order.
data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.sort - b.sort;
});

vat top_parent_id = 1;          // The value of an items parent if it is a top level item.
var sorted = [];                // Empty array to copy sorted elements into.
var skipped = true;             // flag to indicate if any elements have been skipped.
var skip_count = 0;             // Counter to prevent infinite loops.
// Loop until no elements have been skipped. 
//This loops through each level of the tree until all nested branches have been added
while(skipped){
    skipped = false;
    skip_count++;
    if(skip_count === 50){      // Maximum tree depth.
        throw "Error in sorted data or tree depth too great.";
        break;
    }

    // Loop through the data in reverse order; this preserves the branch sort order.
    for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var item = data[i];

        // Skip if this element has already been processed.
        if(item.done)
            continue;

        // If this is this a top level item, then insert and continue.
        if(item.parent == top_parent_id){
            sorted.splice(0, 0, item);          // Insert at the start; last item is the top sort.
            item.done = true;
            continue;
        }

        // Loop the new array to try and find this items parent.
        var found = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < sorted.length; j++) {
            if(item.parent === sorted[j].index){
                sorted.splice(j + 1, 0, item);
                found = true;
                item.done = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // If a place for an item has not been found then skip it for now so it can be tested again on the next iteration.
        if(!found){
            skipped = true;

        }
    }
}
data = sorted;
```